# is BSON representation minified?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I'm working with mongo, one of the documents I'm saving exceeded the maximum 16mb. I wonder if minifying the structure could help in that aspect. So that's why I have the question on the title.
If the bson representation already minify the document, then another attemp by my side it doesn't going to help in anything.

Comment: BSON document is very compact and I'm not sure how will you compact it further without re-writing your own data-store for MongoDB. If your document is exceeding Max limit, I'll suggest to revisit document structure.

Comment: You should probably revisit your data model. 16Mb is a lot. What all are you storing in that one document?. Plus I don't think it will help but what is the store engine you are using? Should be wired tiger as its the default storage engine in the newer mongo versions and performs compression. 

See this for more details :

   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression

Comment: @IshanSoni yea I agreed, my question was more targeted to see if a minified document, representing same structure was equivalent to a non minified document in terms of space usage.

Comment: If your document exceed the max limit 16MB then you can either restructure the model or you can use 'GridFS'.                                                             For Reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB stores data in a BSON representation, where it preserves field names and contents. The total object size depends on the length of the fields as well as the content of the fields. If you're willing to abbreviate your field names, then you could make your document smaller.

You can quickly check this by inserting a document with a long and a short field name:

```
> db.test.insert({abcde:1})
> db.test.stats()
{
  "ns": "test.test",
  "count": 1,
  "size": 37,
  "avgObjSize": 37,
  ...
```

If you can abbreviate the field name, you can achieve some reduction in object size:

```
> db.test2.insert({a:1})
> db.test2.stats()
{
  "ns": "test.test2",
  "count": 1,
  "size": 33,
  "avgObjSize": 33,
  ...
```

From the two examples above, shortening the field name from `abcde` to just `a` resulted in reduction in object size: 37 bytes vs 33 bytes, which is a saving of 4 bytes using a shorter field name.

Comment: excellent, doing your same test, but with fields I also see an increase in size!... maybe minifying an object is not a bad idea after all! (I'm new to mongo and didn't knew about the stats method, it contains lots of useful information :) ).

Answer (score 2):

Document keys eat up a lot of space in BSON since they are stored verbatim, so if you can encode them you'll save a lot of bytes. It can be acceptable if your code will be the only reader of those data, so that no human will have to remember that

```
const MY_INSANELY_LONG_OBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME = "a";

var thePropertyValue = myObject[MY_INSANELY_LONG_OBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you document size become more than 16MB even after minifying it, you can use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) to break that documnet up.

As per MongoDB documentation,

> GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

BSON is already a highly compact format,moreover WiredTiger engine compresses data at page level, not document level.

If you are hitting 16MB limit for your document sizes,you may need to split your documents or redesign your databases.